# SSIS - Extract from XML dtsx Package every SQLCommand / TableorViewName From Data flow task

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, package, extract

Basically, my purpose is urbanization context is to retrieve **ALL** input Datasource (sqlcommand or tableorviewname) and **ALL** output datasources

I did a first try succesfully with one of our dtsx packages :

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS xContent INTO Packages
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'F:\Repos\DW_all\DW_all\anaplan_sales_mrr_v2.dtsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT      
   X.Exe.value('(./@DTS:Description)','nvarchar(20)') as description
   ,X.Exe.value('(./@DTS:ObjectName)','nvarchar(20)') as ObjectName
   ,X.Exe.value('(./DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component/properties/property)[1]','nvarchar(25)') as TargettedTable
   ,X.Exe.value('(./DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component/connections/connection/@connectionManagerRefId)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as TargettedConnect
   ,X.Exe.value('(./DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component[2]/properties/property[1]/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as SourceType
   ,X.Exe.value('(./DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component[2]/properties/property)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [Source]
   ,X.Exe.value('(./DTS:ObjectData/pipeline/components/component[2]/connections/connection/@connectionManagerRefId)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as SourceConnect
FROM    (SELECT XContent  AS pkgXML FROM [dbo].[TestPackage]) t
CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable') X(Exe)
Where  X.Exe.value('(./@DTS:Description)[1]','nvarchar(max)') = 'Data Flow Task'
```

**RESULT :**

| description | ObjectName | TargettedTable | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data Flow Task | 1rst flowname | First Table |  |
| Data Flow Task | Other Flow | other Table |  |
| Data Flow Task | Another Flow | another table |  |

Well, till now everything's fine.
Unfortunately, the properties position and the path is now always the same. In my exemple above, target is the first tag in the XML file (that's why [1]) and source is mentioned after (that's why [2]). But in other packages, that's the reverse case.
In the same idea, the property indicating the type of the datasource (name=sqlcommand or name=tableorviewname) is not always in the same position, so the pointer [1] is not relevant.
Moreover, in my exemple above the path is '/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable' (with one Sequence Container) but other packages don't have container and have a different path (ex: /DTS:Executable/DTS:Executables/DTS:Executable').

I have tried some test with kind of wildcard like [.] or [*] but i'm not confortable with this and my tests are still on failure.

```
<DTS:ObjectData xmlns:DTS="DTS">
        <pipeline
          version="1">
          <components>
            <component
              refId="Package\blabla my description id"
              componentClassID="Microsoft.OLEDBSource"
              contactInfo="OLE DB Source;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;7"
              description="OLE DB Source"
              name="My DataFlow Name"
              usesDispositions="true"
              version="7">
              <properties>
                <property
                  dataType="System.Int32"
                  description="The number of seconds before a command times out.  A value of 0 indicates an infinite time-out."
                  name="CommandTimeout">0</property>
                <property
                  dataType="System.String"
                  description="Specifies the name of the database object used to open a rowset."
                  name="OpenRowset"></property>
                <property
                  dataType="System.String"
                  description="Specifies the variable that contains the name of the database object used to open a rowset."
                  name="OpenRowsetVariable"></property>
                <property
                  dataType="System.String"
                  description="The SQL command to be executed."
                  name="SqlCommand"
UITypeEditor="Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ModalMultilineStringEditor, Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91">SELECT * From OneTable Inner Join AnotherTable ...

</property>
</properties>
</component>
</components>
</pipeline>
</DTS:ObjectData>
```

Can anyone help me please to improve the initial script to make it efficient for whatever packages, resulting all sqlcommand or tableorviewname in input of the dataflows included in the package, and the same in output.

TIA for your help and advices  :-)

Fred.M.

Comment: Can you supply the full XML, it's a hard to work without a [mcve] of an actual valid XML with all the relevant nodes. You can shorten the long inner text if you want

Comment: Thanks Charlieface for your input.
I can't supply the full XML script in the post because it exceeds the maximum of authorized characters. However, I can provide you by mail two examples : I have spent time to anonymize and simplify (by removing useless repetitive tags) two SSIS packages.

Comment: In another way, my request is to be applicable on any SSIS package. So if you have one dtsx file on your side, you can have a try on it.

Comment: You can share it via https://pastebin.com

Comment: "Access Denied.
The website you tried to browse has been considered as harmful. To protect you and the whole company, the access has been denied."
Have you a more secured shared please or email address ?

Comment: You could always use a Google Drive link if you want, there are many other services also

Comment: Shared here :
https://plik.root.gg/file/V2c5P0OLRpiexJP1/y7yHXSjYSAkkuXij/Example1.dtsx
https://plik.root.gg/file/V2c5P0OLRpiexJP1/m7OgUEbnb3rEN36N/Exemple2.dtsx